# How to call a function from another class React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am trying to call a function from another class it throws an error getValue is not a function. i dont want to use static. I hope  there's a solution for it. here's my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SecondClass from "./main"

export default class A extends Component{
  constructor (props) {  
    super(props)

 onPress = ()=>{
   getValue()

 }
}

//SecondClass
export default class SecondClass extends Component{
  constructor (props) {  
    super(props)
  }
  getValues = () => {
    alert("Hello")
  }   
}
```

Comment: if I am understanding correctly, you're trying to call a **method** on the `SecondClass` object inside of `A` when `onPress` gets triggered?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Comment: This is a duplication question. There are answers already written. Use existing answers.

Comment: @SukhiX07 you're going to have to use `static` then, and call it as such: `SecondClass.getValues()` inside of the `onPress` method, but depending on what `getValues` does, it might not work the way you're thinking - for example, if you're trying to get state of the `SecondClass` component inside of the `A` component.

Comment: @goto1 , i know but I static i not a right way to do that because later I can’t set state of my class in static function

Comment: @SukhiX07 what is your end goal? The way you're approaching it right now it won't work.

Comment: My main objective is when user press the button then it should call the method from another class and return Hello. Then later i want to set some properties which i not possible in static function. So thats why i dont want to use static function.

Comment: You can try ...   

 export default class A extends Component{
      constructor (props) {  
        super(props)
    this.callSecondClass=new SecondClass(props);
    }

     public callSecondClass:any;
     onPress = ()=>{
       this.callSecondClass.getValue()
    
     }
    }

Comment: @SukhiX07 your "main objective" can be accomplished by using `static`. What you're trying to do "later" requires a different approach but it's unclear exactly what the "later" step is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define the function in the `A` and then pass the function in the `SecondClass` component as a prop...

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-simple-events
```

You can use this library here you can register your function and can trigger from anywhere in app.

For register your function use `on("eventID", "listenerID", ()=>{//call getValues})` in class `SecondClass`

For Trigger your function use `trigger("eventID", eventData)` in class `A`

After that remove the listener by using `remove("eventID", "listenerID")` from class `SecondClass`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot expect that you can simply call some function in another class because you imported that class. The React way of doing this would be to pass the function as a prop if these are parent-child components. If not, I would highly recommend extracting the common function out from both classes and call them separately.

From the comments, other users have also recommended using `static` function if you absolutely want to couple the function to `Second` class.

> My main objective is when user press the button then it should call the method from another class and return Hello. Then later i want to set some properties which i not possible in static function. So thats why i dont want to use static function

From your sample code it looks like `Second` is a React component ? If this class was made to encapsulate certain behavior then I would recommend turning it into a plain javascript class and then instantiate/use wherever necessary.